# How do i show multiplication of covariances?

Tags: covariance, expected-value

i am trying to show the following

$$Cov(a,b) = \frac {Cov(a,x) * Cov(b,x)} {Var(x)}$$

I am a bit lost on how to expand the numerator term, so i wrote the following

$$Cov(a,b) = \frac {[E[ax]-E[a]E[x]] [E[bx]-E[b]E[x]]} {E(x^2)-E(x)^2}$$

I will appreciate any help on how to evaluate the expected value in the numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cov{\mathrm{Cov}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$The statement you're attempting to prove is not generally true (so no wonder you're having trouble proving it).

Let $A = B \sim N(0, 1)$, so that $\Cov(A, B) = 1$. Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$ be independent of $A$ and $B$, so that $\Cov(A, X) = \Cov(B, X) = 0$. Then the right hand side of your equation is
$$
\frac{\Cov(A, X) \Cov(B, X)}{\Var(X)}
= \frac{0 \cdot 0}{1} = 0
$$
but the left hand side was 1.

Maybe there's some special relationship among $A$, $B$, and $X$ that you haven't stated?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very concise and it makes me see a few other things i have been missing.